# Attempt to run .bat script from VBA fails without error code

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

SUMMARY:
I am trying to run a .bat script on a Windows machine using Excel VBA.  I have found references online describing how to do this, and I have followed the instructions contained therein.  However, my .bat file is not running.

DETAILS:
My .bat file ("test.bat") contains the following code:

```
echo off
echo This is a test...
pause
exit
```

It is located on my desktop, with the following path: "C:\Users\User1\Desktop".  When I double-click this .bat file or call it from the command line, it exhibits the desired behavior.  Namely, it pauses and waits for me to press any key.

I am trying to run this same .bat file from Excel VBA using the following code:

```
Sub testBatchScript()

    'Print a message to the immediate window to confirm subroutine execution
    Debug.Print "The subroutine is running."

    'Initialize a windows shell object
    Dim wsh As WshShell
    Set wsh = New WshShell

    'Construct the full path to the .bat file
    Dim fullPath As String
    fullPath = Chr(34) + "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test.bat" + Chr(34)

    'Run the .bat file
    Dim eCode As Long
    eCode = wsh.Run(fullPath, waitonreturn:=True, windowstyle:=1)

    If eCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("An error occurred.")
    End If

End Sub
```

When I run this subroutine, nothing happens.  No CMD window pops up, and no message box indicating an error pops up.  However, I do know that the subroutine is running, due to the message that appears in the immediate window.

I'm stumped as to why this isn't working.  What's even more perplexing is that I was able to successfully call .bat scripts from VBA as recently as a few weeks ago..

Anyone have any explanation or suggestions?

UPDATE1:
Following @Dhamo's suggestion in the comments below, I have updated the VBA code with error handling:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testBatchScript()

    On Error GoTo EH:

    'Print a message to the immediate window to confirm subroutine execution
    Debug.Print "The subroutine is running."

    'Initialize a windows shell object
    Dim wsh As WshShell
    Set wsh = New WshShell

    'Construct the full path to the .bat file
    Dim fullPath As String
    fullPath = Chr(34) + "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test.bat" + Chr(34)

    'Run the .bat file
    Dim eCode As Long
    eCode = wsh.Run(fullPath, waitonreturn:=True, windowstyle:=1)

    If eCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("An error occurred.")
    End If

    Exit Sub

EH:
    MsgBox ("The error description is: " & Err.Description)

End Sub
```

When I run *this* code, still nothing happens.

UPDATE2:
I ran the test code again this morning, after restarting my computer, and *this* time I got a pop-up message saying: "The error description is: Permission denied".  I then ran the code again to see if I could replicate this error message, and there was no pop-up!  Furthermore, I can't get the error message to reappear no matter how many times I run the code.  So restarting seems to have done something...

The "Permission denied" message suggests that it's a security issue.  Anyone have any ideas for solving it?

Comment: Have you added 'Windows Script Host Object Model' reference ? if not already please add it and try [? == VBA window, click Tools > References]

Comment: @Dhamo: Yes, I have.

Comment: @Dhamo: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "try [? == VBA window...".

Comment: Add option explicit in the first line and also enable error handler [on error goto EH:] and also define the EH [EH: msgbox err.description]. At least you will get to know the actual issue to some extent. The above code is working fine for me [I use v2016]

Comment: If you've already added the reference, you can ignore further comment

Comment: @Dhamo, Sure, let me implement the error handler.  Give me a bit...

Comment: @Dhamo: It's done.  See the update above.

Comment: You didn't implement the error handler properly. You need `Exit Sub` right before `EH`, otherwise you execute `EH` regardless of what happens.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Sorry, I'm inexperienced in the use of error handlers.  I'll fix that.  One moment...

Comment: @JohnColeman: I've fixed the error handler.  See the update above.

Comment: Your code works for me (with the path details changed). It also works for me without the `Chr(34)`. Maybe drop those and see what happens. How are you invoking this sub?

Comment: @JohnColeman: I'm invoking the subroutine by clicking in the text and pressing the F5 key.  But I get the same result if I call it from the Immediate window.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Removing chr(34) from the beginning and end of the string makes no difference for me.

Comment: What happens if you turn your VBA code into pure VBScript? Get Excel out of the loop.

Comment: Have you tried using just `Shell` ? as in `batFile = Shell("FilePath\filename.bat", 1)`

Comment: @RicardoA: I need the "waitonreturn" feature, so Shell is not an option for me.  That being said, I just tried it for the sake of debugging.  No difference in behavior.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Forgive my ignorance, but I don't know how to turn my VBA code into VBScript.  Would I need Visual Studio for this?

Comment: @RicardoA: To elaborate on my previous comment, when I use the Shell function, it returns a nonzero Double, which, according to this source (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) indicates success.  However, the .bat file is still not popping up and waiting for me to press any key.  So, again, I'd say it's essentially the same behavior.

Comment: upload the workbook for us take a look

Comment: @user2648008: Here's a link to a copy of the workbook: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1He05Aa7gA4X5G89EHUTBxd4FewVdCfVx

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:

If you put the following into a file, save it as test.vbs (not as a text document: notepad will create test.vbs.txt if you are not careful):

```
Dim wsh, fullPath, ecode
Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
fullPath = "C:\programs\test.bat"
ecode = wsh.Run(fullPath, 1, True)
msgbox(ecode)
```

(with the full path adjusted to your situation). Save it to e.g. the desktop and click the icon. What happens?

Comment: So I suppose that means that Excel is the problem?  Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. I've never encountered something like that. It is almost like Excel is sending a keystroke to the command window before you can see it.

Comment: I've changed the .bat file so that it instead of waiting for a keystroke, it creates a separate .txt file.  This .txt file is not created when I try to call the .bat script from VBA.  So it's not that Excel is sending a keystroke before I can see the window.

Comment: It could be a windows security "feature". It may not like doing Excel -> VBA -> Bat file, but it likes just doing VBS -> Bat file. Also did you try removing these: `, waitonreturn:=True, windowstyle:=1` and just doing `1, True` in Excel like the VBS?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it might be a security thing... But, if so, why does it seem to only affect me?

Comment: Also, I just tried `1, True` as the arguments.  No difference.

Comment: UPDATE2 above suggests that it is indeed a security issue.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @Garrett "Permission denied" sounds more like administrative privileges question than a security question, although I guess it could have been the latter. If this is a work computer and you have an IT department -- perhaps they introduced some change? Also, perhaps some anti-malware product is preventing it from running? If that is the case, there should be some log files that you can look at (e.g. the Malwarebytes control panel has a log tab).

Comment: @JohnColeman: Your intuition was correct again, John!  It looks like Bitdefender is blocking the activity, based on the program's log.  Now I just need to figure out how to make Bitdefender allow this particular action without becoming too permissive...